# How to fix the IE/FF displaying image issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Chrome output:

[image]

IE10 output:

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr class="section group vertAlignT">
        <td class="col span_img_text_image span_pad_right vertAlignT">
            <div class="hidOverflow">
                <div class="captionBottom">
                    <a href="/article.aspx" title=""><img id="NewsArticle_3080_image" class="imgArtThumb" title="" alt="" src="lungs.jpg" /></a>
                    <figcaption>View Full Article!</figcaption>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col span_img_text_text span_pad_left vertAlignT">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="/article.aspx" title="" class="defaultLinks setBold">Taking Steps to Prevent Lung Cancer</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="serviceHolder hidOverflow"><span>blah blah blah text...</span></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    /*display: block;*/
    /*float:left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before, .group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}
.span_img_text_image {
    width: 32.2%;
}
.span_img_text_text {
    width: 65.1%;
}
.span_pad_right {
    padding-right: 1%;
}
.hidOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.vertAlignT {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.captionBottom {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #e55302;
    background: rgba(229,83,2,0.90);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.captionBottom:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.captionBottom:before {
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
.captionBottom figcaption {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -30%;
}
.captionBottom:hover figcaption {
    bottom: 0;
}
.imgArtThumb {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.serviceHolder {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I make IE display the same way? It is displaying like that in IE10 where image is expanding but overflowing outside of the DIV.

[image]

Comment: Lol at applying responsive column styles to table columns ;)

First of all: do NOT use tables. As it is not tabular data you are displaying. Furthermore, I don't know where you got the grid css from (it's not bootstrap), but checkout the documentation from the site you got it from. Most definetly there are some examples there...

Comment: I am using an Ektron collection and would like to split to the next line after every two entry of articles. Is there a way to do that without using Table?

Comment: This is one is going to be tricky without a Fiddle.

Comment: I will create one for you. Thanks.

Comment: @Dura Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/2bbwwj6y/ (If you make the window a little small the image gets cut off instead of resizing) The content is generated by XSL which ensures there is a new "row" for every 3rd article.

Comment: aah, I was thinking of the text as it is displaying like that in your question. but it's an image!!! :)_ use max-width: 100% for that image.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal Can you please check the fiddle and let me know if the solution will fix it. Now it seems the issue is in IE10 and FF and not in Chrome.

Comment: I have updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bbwwj6y/4/). Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, what did you do so I can just update my CSS that is needed. Chrome was showing correctly and not IE/FF! :)

Comment: I'll put it in answer.

Comment: Seems like everything is the same to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bbwwj6y/4/).

Updated CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    /*display: block;*/
    /*float:left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before, .group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}
.span_img_text_image {
    width: 32.2%;
}
.span_img_text_text {
    width: 65.1%;
}
.span_pad_right {
    padding-right: 1%;
}
.hidOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.vertAlignT {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.captionBottom {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #e55302;
    background: rgba(229,83,2,0.90);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.captionBottom:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.captionBottom:before {
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
.captionBottom figcaption {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -30%;
}
.captionBottom:hover figcaption {
    bottom: 0;
}
.imgArtThumb {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.serviceHolder {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.span_half {
    width: 48.5%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

I just got rid of `display: inline block` in the class `captionBottom`.

Comment: WOW... Silly me. Thanks. It is working now :) Thanks again. +1 and Accept!

Comment: Not only IE but FF as well :/ That is where I was baffled... *SIGH* :D